# Do I remove the JSON tag from a question?

Tags: discussion, tags

People often ask questions about "JSON Objects" when in reality they mean Javascript objects. In these cases, do I remove the JSON tag from the question? If so, do I then have to remove all references to the word JSON within the question? Or do I just leave as-is and let the comments deal with it?

A good example is this question: [Create new array sorted by time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132968/create-new-json-object-sorting-by-time)

Answer (score 8):

The OP realised his mistake soon after posting the question, and [corrected the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23132968/2).

To answer your question: yes, edit the question and the tags.